# XML/JSON object used in offline mobile web app

Tags: c#, json, xml, asp.net-mvc

I have a web app that is used for multiple choice tests. The tests are done on tablets (iPad's/Android Tablets). The problem I have is that the test runs slow as the the previous developers made ajax calls that made calls to the DB for each and every part of the test screen (Image, Question, Answer Bloc, Scenarios etc.) The test only shows one question on the screen and on Next/Previous click it goes of and separately gets the data.

**EXTRA INFO:** The tests consists out of 40 - 45 questions and it can be that all questions have images as well.

I have already changed the code to build one object that consists all the questions images and information needed.

What I want to know is, is it possible to convert the entire object to either `xml` or `json` object (I have done the code to do the conversion already) and somehow store the `xml`/`json` object in the AppCache/Manifest so that the system does one call to the DB, gets all the info when you start the test, so the initial load is slow, but then use the cached object for the rest of the paper so that it runs a lot faster?

If it is indeed possible, can you provide an example of how to use this and if not, what would be the next best thing as I really want to improve the speed of the test.

Also maybe as an alternative, can you create an `XML` file and then store that file locally so that the mobile web app can access the data stored in there? Because there might be a chance that a larger image is used which might exceed the 5mb Cache limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [`SessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or [`LocalStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) in the browser. It let's you store data in the browser either for the duration of the browser session (until the browser is closed) or permanently, respectively.

You can access them on the `window` object and use them as simple key-value storage:

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');

// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem('key');

// Remove all saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.clear();
```

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for the suggestions. I took a look at both Session and Local storage. The primary device used for the testing at schools are iPad's thus iOS and according to the links provided since iOS 5.5 the system can clear out the cache if need be. This is just a bit worrisome that the stored information gets cleared during a test.

Comment: It's very seldom this happens while it's in active use. However I'd consider being able to load the questions from cache 90% of the a lot better than 0%. Do a check if the data is still there and reload it if it isn't.

Comment: "However I'd consider being able to load the questions from cache 90% of the a lot better than 0%." that's true...I will have a look and play around with it. If it does help my case I will mark this as the answer! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If this is already an Ajax application then you could consider making it into a single-page application so that you never do a full "new page" request from the server, but only make Ajax requests and update the page as required. In that case any data you get from the server can be kept in ordinary Javascript variables.

(It would be fun to write this application using Saxon-JS, but you're probably not wanting to look at a total rewrite...)

Comment: The current web app layout consists of the main Test View and then 3 - 4 partial view's (answer option, question, scenario, image). Would you suggest it be better that I create one view, do a single Ajax call and then populate the Div's and fields? 

Because now it's doing a Ajax call to load one part, then as that one is done, there is a ajax call to fetch the data for each partial view and return it in succession. Which I feel is unnecessary DB calls and process.

Thoughts?

Comment: We're getting into design questions here rather than coding, and I prefer not to advise on design unless I have done a careful study of the requirements. That's not really possible in the StackOverflow format.